# In a survey where subjects can select more than one option, how can I clean the data to create new levels (multiple options selected)?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, data-cleaning, analysis

I'm working with survey data and subjects are asked to select which drug/substance they have come into contact with. There are about 10 options, and participants can select one or more options. When I go to process the data, I would like to be able to create levels that go beyond "more than 1 option selected" or "more than 2 options selected", considering that I would like to create levels such as "alcohol AND another substance listed" or "marijuana AND another substance" (specifying levels by name, not just number of options selected).

I think once the general syntax is clear, it can then be modified to create other levels based on particular substances, multiple substances together, or a level that involves more than 2/3 options selected.

I have used syntax for a question on sexual orientation that I've used already where I coded a new level of the variable to be "more than one option selected". (below)

```
orientation is my dataframe containing the question
sexual_orientation is the column name

df <- unique(orientation[, c('subject_id', 'sexual_orientation')])
pids_multiple_answers <- 
df %>%
dplyr::group_by('subject_id') %>%
dplyr::summarise(n_answers = n_distinct(sexual_orientation)) 
pids_multiple_answers <- pids_multiple_answers[pids_multiple_answers$n_answers >1,]

df[df$'subject_id %in% c(pids_multiple_answers$subject_id), 'sexual_orientation'] <- 'multiple selections'
df <- unique(df)
```

This works fine for something like sexual orientation, but for this substance use question, given that there are a lot of options and a substantial amount of subjects are selecting more than 1 option, I'd like to try and be able to write syntax which would allow me to explore those levels a bit more clearly. Here is example data illustrating the substance use question:

```
structure(list(subjectID = c("xxx12", "xxx13", "xxx14", "xxx14", 
"xxx14", "xxx15", "xxx15", "xxx18", "xxx19", "xxx20", "xxx20"
), substance = c("alcohol", "alcohol", "marijuana", "alcohol", 
"stimulant", "alcohol", "stimulant", "alcohol", "marijuana", 
"alcohol", "marijuana")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

How can I create a new variable where, based on the above example data, I can code that subject14 and 20 had alcohol selected and at least one additional choice, for instance? I'd like to create syntax that would allow me to have each subject on its own row, with classification of which substance(s) and how many, for instance, being that new variable.

Thank you!

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data you are using and pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Thanks for the link! Here is a small reproducible dataset that I crafted that helps to illustrate my question better!                                                                                            
structure(list(subjectID = c("xxx12", "xxx13", "xxx14", "xxx14", 
"xxx14", "xxx15", "xxx15", "xxx18", "xxx19", "xxx20", "xxx20"
), substance = c("alcohol", "alcohol", "marijuana", "alcohol", 
"stimulant", "alcohol", "stimulant", "alcohol", "marijuana", 
"alcohol", "marijuana")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))

Comment: Great! If you can paste it in your question, that would be better. Also it still looks like you are missing parts of your data here, such as the `sexual_orientation` variable.

Comment: Thanks, Shawn! The sexual_orientation variable was just an example of a variable I had already worked the syntax for; however, I think that something similar COULD be applied to the substance abuse problem! Hopefully my edit to the question can clear things up a bit.